# SUMO TraCI how can i get id junction by ID vehicle or ID edge?

Tags: python, sumo

I need the junction that vehicle is approaching
I mean the vehicle on the junction lane
This is the junction I need

I can get the lane and edge by

```
edge = traci.vehicle.getRoadID(id_veh])
lane = traci.vehicle.getLaneID(id_veh)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution is to parse the network with sumolib and get the junction from there:

```
# import the library
import sumolib
# parse the net
net = sumolib.net.readNet('myNet.net.xml')

# retrieve the successor node ID of an edge
nextNodeID = net.getEdge('myEdgeID').getToNode().getID()
```

This is directly from the [examples](https://sumo.dlr.de/docs/Tools/Sumolib.html#import_a_network_and_retrieve_nodes_and_edges)